# setting the default applications for a file type in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hai all,

In my iphone application i want to open a my custom application(available in the iphone)   when the user tapes on a particular type file sent by email or MMS ,

for example, if i sent an music file (via email or MMS) with a custom extension (for eg: .muc)  i want to open my application (lets say myMusicPlayer) to play that file,

is there any way to do that in iphone ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this exactly. The only way to open an application is using a URL scheme assigned to your app via the Info.plist file but you wouldn't be able to send the local file system location of your file to it.